# How to work with Collection objects to get desired Collection in Groovy

Tags: json, parsing, data-structures, groovy, collections

I know little bit of Java but no much idea of groovy. I have got the below result by using some of my groovy knowledge and used groupBy collection operation `results.groupBy({ plan -> plan.planItem.self })` to reach until this.

I want to compare and get the earliest `startDate` and latest `endDate` for the `planItem.self` URL ending with `TEST-2`. You can see that the `TEST-2` has 2 entries with different `startDate` and `endDate`. The final object I want is with only one `TEST-2` entry but dates as mentioned above, and remove all objects but one. Similarly for all the pages such as `AP-3`, `AP-1`.
I have a collection object as shown below (you may notice there are multiple objects for `TEST-2` and `AP-3`).

```
{
 "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      },
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-17",
      "endDate": "2020-05-20",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-27",
      "endDate": "2020-05-27",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-18",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the output object I want to make is as given below (you may notice that in the output collection there's only one object for `TEST-2` and `AP-3`) and also removed the unnecessary attributes. Please guide me to use the best of the Groovy operations to make the whole process faster because I have only 60 seconds to run these operations along with REST calls which I will make once I have these objects ready in the format I want, so processing time is of high importance.

```
{
 "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-20"
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-27"
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17"
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-18"
    }
  ]
}
```

The dates shoud be converted from String to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the basic structure from your group-by.  Next want for each
map value the minimum of all startDate and the maximum of all endDate.  E.g.
this works:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

println(data.collectEntries{ url, plans ->
    [url, [startDate: plans*.startDate.min(), endDate: plans*.endDate.max()]]
}.inspect())

// → ['https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2':['startDate':'2020-05-16', 'endDate':'2020-05-20'], 'https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3':['startDate':'2020-05-16', 'endDate':'2020-05-27'], 'https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1':['startDate':'2020-05-16', 'endDate':'2020-05-17'], 'https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4':['startDate':'2020-05-16', 'endDate':'2020-05-18']]
```

This create a new map, keeps the key from the original and creates a new map as
value from the list, where all startDate:s get collected (via the spread
operator) and then get the minimum from that (the strings as dates are already
nicely sortable).  Same for endDate with the maximum.

Comment: Can you please explain this `plans*.startDate.min()` part?

Comment: "where all startDate:s get collected (via the spread operator) and then get the minimum from that" - that is short for `plans.collect{ it.startDate }.min()` - take all startdate from plans, then take the minimum of that.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and to the point answer. I am able to achieve what I wanted to achieve with the above snippet.

Comment: Before running min() or max() I want to convert those startDate and endDate string values into date values using, for example, Date.parse(). How can I do that in the same collectEntries? Because running max() on string date list gives wrong max date.